# When appended a copy of list into another list, after altering the original list it also gets altered in another list

Tags: python, python-3.x, copy

```
k=[
[7, 1, 3, 6, 8, 5, 5, 6, 4],
[7, 2, 6, 2, 2, 8, 3, 9, 6],
[3, 3, 8, 6, 1, 3, 4, 5, 9],
[4, 5, 9, 8, 6, 6, 1, 3, 4],
[2, 8, 1, 4, 8, 6, 9, 5, 1],
[4, 7, 8, 6, 1, 8, 5, 8, 4],
[6, 7, 6, 4, 8, 6, 6, 7, 2],
[9, 8, 6, 3, 8, 8, 5, 5, 9],
[9, 5, 7, 5, 1, 1, 8, 6, 5]
]
a=[]
c=0

def foo():
    global a
    global k
    global c
    a.append(k.copy())
    print(a)
    for i in range(9):
        for j in range(9):
            k[i][j]=1
    print(a)

foo()
```

Expected Output:

> [[[7, 1, 3, 6, 8, 5, 5, 6, 4], [7, 2, 6, 2, 2, 8, 3, 9, 6], [3, 3, 8, 6, 1, 3, 4, 5, 9], [4, 5, 9, 8, 6, 6, 1, 3, 4], [2, 8, 1, 4, 8, 6, 9, 5, 1], [4, 7, 8, 6, 1, 8, 5, 8, 4], [6, 7, 6, 4, 8, 6, 6, 7, 2], [9, 8, 6, 3, 8, 8, 5, 5, 9], [9, 5, 7, 5, 1, 1, 8, 6, 5]]]

> [[[7, 1, 3, 6, 8, 5, 5, 6, 4], [7, 2, 6, 2, 2, 8, 3, 9, 6], [3, 3, 8, 6, 1, 3, 4, 5, 9], [4, 5, 9, 8, 6, 6, 1, 3, 4], [2, 8, 1, 4, 8, 6, 9, 5, 1], [4, 7, 8, 6, 1, 8, 5, 8, 4], [6, 7, 6, 4, 8, 6, 6, 7, 2], [9, 8, 6, 3, 8, 8, 5, 5, 9], [9, 5, 7, 5, 1, 1, 8, 6, 5]]]

Generated Output:

> [[[7, 1, 3, 6, 8, 5, 5, 6, 4], [7, 2, 6, 2, 2, 8, 3, 9, 6], [3, 3, 8, 6, 1, 3, 4, 5, 9], [4, 5, 9, 8, 6, 6, 1, 3, 4], [2, 8, 1, 4, 8, 6, 9, 5, 1], [4, 7, 8, 6, 1, 8, 5, 8, 4], [6, 7, 6, 4, 8, 6, 6, 7, 2], [9, 8, 6, 3, 8, 8, 5, 5, 9], [9, 5, 7, 5, 1, 1, 8, 6, 5]]]

> [[[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]]

Comment: Also check [What is the difference between a deep copy and a shallow copy?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/184710/4046632)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With copy() you perform a shallow copy.
You need a deep copy. See [Docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy) for more information

> The difference between shallow and deep copying is only relevant for compound objects (objects that contain other objects, like lists or class instances):

> A shallow copy constructs a new compound object and then (to the extent possible) inserts references into it to the objects found in the original.

> A deep copy constructs a new compound object and then, recursively, inserts copies into it of the objects found in the original.

```
from copy import deepcopy

a.append(deepcopy(k))
print(a)
for i in range(9):
    for j in range(9):
        k[i][j]=1
print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

`.copy` method of list is shallow, you need to use `copy.deepcopy` if you want to get totally independent copy, consider following example

```
import copy
k1 = [[1,2],[3,4]]
k2 = k1.copy()
k3 = copy.deepcopy(k1)
k1[0][0] = 0
print(k2)
print(k3)
```

output

```
[[0, 2], [3, 4]]
[[1, 2], [3, 4]]
```

Using `.copy` is fine if you are working with flat list of immutable objects, you have `list` of `list` which are mutable.